# Memory leaks in Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, memory-leaks

Can somebody help me here?. New as iPhone Developer. I am getting a memory leak in Core Data, and I don't see how to fix it. I am running this method several times in a UIViewController ( I am not using Table Viiew):

```
-(void)fetchEvents: (NSString *) predicateSearch localEvent:thisEvent {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [thisEvent managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [thisEvent entity];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    // Predicate for main screen
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type matches %@", predicateSearch];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (fetchResults == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    [self setMyPhotoEventsArray:fetchResults];

    [request release];

}  // fetchEvents
```

And I am getting these memory leaks in Instruments:!

```
Leaked Object # Address Size Responsible Library Responsible Frame  
_PFArray 3 < multiple > 96 CoreData -[NSSQLCore _prepareResultsFromResultSet:usingFetchPlan:withMatchingRows:]

Leaked Object # Address Size Responsible Library Responsible Frame  
GeneralBlock-32 2 < multiple > 64 CoreData PF_ALLOCATE_OBJECT_ARRAY
```

The method runs fine, however, I keep getting these leaks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from what you show here, but here's a guess:

[self setMyPhotoEventsArray: fetchResults] probably retains "fetchResults" and then in the View Controller's dealloc and viewDidUnload you may be forgetting to release them.

As such, when the view controller is dismissed, the reference to the array is lost, and you have a leak.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will look into this, the part that confuses me is getting all these leaks from Core Data.